# Specialization of casting operator to template argument

Tags: c++

I can't find this question answered in any other place, so I finally decided to ask.
I have a C++ templated class that includes a casting operator to the type of one of the arguments:

```
template <class E, class B>
class bar {
    private:
        B innerVal_;
    [...]
    public:
        /* Casting to the type of the 2nd template argument */
        operator B() const { return innerVal_; }; // default implementation provided
};
```

However, I need to provide a specialization of this casting operator for some specific template arguments, for instance:

```
template<>
bar<concreteType,int>::operator int() // <-- whoops, error!
{ [...] }
```

The thing is that, no matter how I specify the syntax of the casting operator, gcc consistently returns me an error referred to the declaration of the function. The most common one is:

> error: template-id ‘operator int<>’ for ‘bar< concreteType, int>::operator int()’ does not match any template declaration.

Which I got with these lines:

- Defining the casting operator as "operator int()"
- Using "operator typeB()", after declaring in the original template a line "typedef B typeB;"

I also played around with the "typename" keyword, with template brackets, and made some other desperate attempts. All of them result in bizarre errors --that I'm not going even to paste here.

Am I losing some obvious detail? Do you have any hint/pointer for me? Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ you cannot specialize a member function on the template parameters of the class.  So here's the workaround:

```
template <class E, class B>
class bar_base {  //base class with 99% of the implementation
    private:
        B innerVal_;
    public:
    [...] //most of your members here
};
template <class E, class B>
class bar : public bar_base<E,B> { //normal instantiation
public:
    [...] //constructors only
    /* Casting to the type of the 2nd template argument */
    operator B() const { return innerVal_; }; // default implementation provided
};
template <class E>
class bar<E,int> : public bar_base<E,int> { //E,int specialization
public:
    [...] //constructors only
    operator int() const { [...]};
};
```

or, much simpler now that I think on it:

```
private:
    template<class T>
    T convert_to() {return innerVal_; }
    template<>
    int convert_to<int>() {return innerVal_; }
public:
    operator B() const { return convert_to<B>(); };
```

Comment: Ehm... thank you for the fast response, but I don't really undersand your answer. What do you exactly mean by "partial speciallization"? As far as I know, my specialization was full:
    template<> //<-- no arguments, full specialization
    bar<type1,type2>::operator type2() {...}
(I've changed the types to type1, type2, which are supossed to be real types: let's suppose type1=type2=int).

On the other hand, isn't it there a solution not involving inheritance?. Thank you.

Comment: @dunadar: It's not possible to specialize a member function on the template parameters of the class either.  You'll have to use inheritance, or be crafty with SFINAE (which I'm not.  Also, I'm not sure you can SFINAE conversion operators easily.  I'll think on it.)

Comment: @dunadar: I dawned on me that all you have to do is make the function into a _template_ function, and everything is fine and dandy.  Answer updated.

Comment: Wow, nifty solution! I love it: keeps the code small and "simple" --as simpler as templates allow, I mean. I will try it as soon as possible, but I'm sure it'll work.
Thank you for your help and patience.